# cURL Fuction not POSTing to other domain

Tags: php, post, curl, cross-site

So I have some variables in one of my php file and I want to send those variables data to another domain. So I was using cURL function.

```
<?php
function post_to_url($url, $data) {
$fields = '';
foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
  $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
}
rtrim($fields, '&');

$post = curl_init();

curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($post);
echo $result;

curl_close($post);
}

$data = array(
   "name" => "c.bavota",
   "website" => "http://bavotasan.com",
   "twitterID" => "bavotasan"
);

post_to_url("http://anotherdomain.com/receive.php", $data);
//header("location: http://anotherdomain.com/receive.php");
?>
```

Contents of my receive.php file is-

```
<?php
echo $_POST["name"];
?>
```

And I get a blank page.
Where am I going wrong? Is there another way to fetch the result on receiving end?
Also when I tried following with an idetical receive.php I get nothing but blank page.

```
post_to_url("http://samedomain.com/receive.php", $data);
```

Comment: added the "PHP" tag. Please never forget to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As if you are using `curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`. CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER tells PHP to store the response in a variable instead of printing it or redirecting to the page. you don't have to redirect to page for showing request you can directly do following:

```
$result = curl_exec($post);
echo $result;//show result expected ==> "c.bavota"
```

> Curl won't redirect to any page. But you can see response at same time.

You are getting blank page because of you are using `header("location: http://anotherdomain.com/receive.php");` means you are again hitting `GET` request to page.

---

Instead of using `curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);` try:

```
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

Comment: I removed header and added echo $result; Now I m getting message in my browser "307 Temporary Redirect"

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. That flaw happened when I was copying my code to stack overflow. That was not in case of my original code. I corrected in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your $url parameter is not being used. You are using an undefined variable for the URL:

```
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url2); // Undefined $url2?
```

PHP usually tells you when there's a problem like this. However I would assume you have certain error checking turned off.

Comment: I am sorry. That flaw happened when I was copying my code to stack overflow. That was not in case of my original code. I corrected in the question.

Comment: Ok. I would try to echo something else other than the $_POST variable to see if you are actually reaching the file. If it works then I would guess either that the name parameter isn't being properly posted or if it's still blank there are errors happening on receive.php server.